Blazor Web App and Duende IdentityServer keeps getting logged out
I've set up the following,

Duende IdentityServer (IDP)
API
Blazor Web App (.Net 8)
The Web App consists of a Server and Client project.

When logging in I get authenticated and able to retrieve data from the API. All is good. The problem is that I get logged out if the user is idle for about 5 minutes.
I've set up offline_access for the use of reqest token, but whatever changes I try - I still get logged off having 5 min of idle time.
I've even set the access token lifetime to 2 hours on the IDP config as a workaround, but that seems to have no effect. A little bit of idle time and I'm routed back to the login page of the IDP.
AccessTokenLifetime = 7200
IdentityTokenLifetime = 7200
Not quite sure where to look anymore. Anyone who can shed some light on what I am missing?
Here's some of the most relevant setup
--------- Duende IDP Config --------------------------
new Client
{
    ClientId = "test.blazor.webapp",
    ClientName = "TestApp",
    RequireClientSecret = true,

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

    RedirectUris = configuration.GetSection("BlazorWebApp:RedirectUris").Get<string[]>(),
    FrontChannelLogoutUri = configuration.GetSection("BlazorWebApp:FrontChannelLogoutUri").Get<string>(),
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = configuration.GetSection("BlazorWebApp:PostLogoutRedirectUris").Get<string[]>(),
    AccessTokenLifetime = 7200,           
    IdentityTokenLifetime = 7200,      
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "roles", "testapi" }
},

------------Server Blazor-----------------------------------
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();

builder.Services.ConfigureAuthentication(builder);
builder.Services.ConfigureCookieOidcRefresh(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, PersistingAuthenticationStateProvider>();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

------------Server Blazor (ConfigureAuthentication)-----------------------------------
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
  options.Authority = builder.Configuration.GetSection("IDP:Authority").Get<string>();
  options.ClientId = "test.blazor.webapp";
  options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
  options.MapInboundClaims = false; 
  options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Name;
  options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";

  options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
  options.SaveTokens = false;  

  options.Scope.Add(OpenIdConnectScope.OfflineAccess);
  options.Scope.Add(OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile);
  options.Scope.Add("roles");
  options.Scope.Add("testapi");

  options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

  options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-oidc");
  options.SignedOutCallbackPath = new PathString("/signout-callback-oidc");
  options.RemoteSignOutPath = new PathString("/signout-oidc");
});

  builder.Services.AddOpenIdConnectAccessTokenManagement();

  return services;
}

----------------Client Blazor -------------------------------
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AuthenticationStateProvider, PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider>();

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });


await builder.Build().RunAsync();

--- PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider.cs (blazor client) ---
internal sealed class PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
  private static readonly Task<AuthenticationState> defaultUnauthenticatedTask =
      Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity())));

  private readonly Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask = defaultUnauthenticatedTask;

  public PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider(PersistentComponentState state)
  {
    if (!state.TryTakeFromJson<UserInfo>(nameof(UserInfo), out var userInfo) || userInfo is null)
    {
      return;
    }

    authenticationStateTask = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(userInfo.ToClaimsPrincipal()));
  }

public override Task GetAuthenticationStateAsync() => authenticationStateTask;
}
--- PersistingAuthenticationStateProvider.cs (blazor server) -----
internal sealed class PersistingAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider, IHostEnvironmentAuthenticationStateProvider, IDisposable
{
    private const string CLAIM_NAME = "name";
    private const string CLAIM_NAMEIDENTIFIER = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier";

    private readonly IAppUsersApiService _appUsersApiService;
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly IUserApiService _userApiService;

    private readonly PersistentComponentState persistentComponentState;
    private readonly PersistingComponentStateSubscription subscription;
    private Task<AuthenticationState>? authenticationStateTask;

    public PersistingAuthenticationStateProvider(PersistentComponentState state, HttpClient httpClient, IUserApiService userApiService, IAppUsersApiService appUsersApiService)
    {
        persistentComponentState = state;
        subscription = state.RegisterOnPersisting(OnPersistingAsync, RenderMode.InteractiveWebAssembly);
        _httpClient = httpClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpClient));
        _userApiService = userApiService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userApiService));
        _appUsersApiService = appUsersApiService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(appUsersApiService));
    }

    public async override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        if (authenticationStateTask == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                $"Do not call {nameof(GetAuthenticationStateAsync)} " +
                "outside of the DI scope for a Razor component. " +
                "Typically, this means you can call it only within a Razor component or inside another DI service that is resolved for a Razor component."
            );
        }
        else
        {
            if (authenticationStateTask.Result?.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true)
            {
                // Check if user exists, if not create it
                try
                {
                    var user = await _appUsersApiService.Get();
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException e)
                {
                    if (e.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                    {
                        //User does not exist, create it
                        var email = authenticationStateTask.Result.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == CLAIM_NAME)?.Value;

                        var userId = (authenticationStateTask.Result.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == CLAIM_NAMEIDENTIFIER)?.Value);
                        if(userId == null)
                        {
                            userId = (authenticationStateTask.Result.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub")?.Value);
                        }
                        if(userId == null)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("User id is null or empty");
                        }                        

                        var newUser = new AppUserForCreateDto
                        {
                            Email = email,
                            IdentityId = Guid.Parse(userId)
                        };
                        await _userApiService.CreateUser(newUser);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return authenticationStateTask.Result;
    }
    //public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync() =>
    //    authenticationStateTask ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(
    //        $"Do not call {nameof(GetAuthenticationStateAsync)} " +
    //        "outside of the DI scope for a Razor component. " +
    //        "Typically, this means you can call it only within a Razor component or inside another DI service that is resolved for a Razor component."
    //    );

    public void SetAuthenticationState(Task<AuthenticationState> task)
    {
        authenticationStateTask = task;
    }

    private async Task OnPersistingAsync()
    {
        var authenticationState = await GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var principal = authenticationState.User;

        if (principal.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true)
        {
            persistentComponentState.PersistAsJson(nameof(UserInfo), UserInfo.FromClaimsPrincipal(principal));
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        subscription.Dispose();
    }
}

After more examination, it seems to happen when the server shutdown due to user idle time (which is set to 5 minutes). When restarting on the next request it does not seem to have it's refresh_token available anymore.

could i be that one of the cookies expires?

The cookies checked at the browser, is set to expire in several days ahead.

Could you post the code of PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider?

I've added both the persisting and persistent to the post. I've checked that I do receive the id_token, access_token and refresh_token from Duende.
